# How to fix " error message: 'Received RST_STREAM with error code 8'" in compiling tensorflow using bazel

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to compile the latest tensorflow version (2.0) using bazel (0.24.1):

```
~/bin/bazel build -c opt --verbose_failures --copt=-msse3 --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I receive the following error messages:

```
Server terminated abruptly (error code: 1, error message: 'Received RST_STREAM with error code 8', log file: '/home/zhang/.cache/bazel/_bazel_zhang/72e7c60ab7642c4e9dd9ba0bb5e0d8db/server/jvm.out')
```

In the jvm.out file, it looks like:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/home/zhang/.cache/bazel/_bazel_zhang/install/7da6a92c096ada842b8d48c251312343/_embedded_binaries/A-server.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Please help me out. Thanks!